# if my phone shuts down, does my google incognito tabs stay up?

Tags: browser

My phone received water damage and I had some stuff up that i don't want my parents to see if they manage to make it working again? Do my tabs stay open or do they close?

Comment: Well, @Izzy I guess instead of putting comments over here I guess I would remove this one out move forward and write my answer over the answer box! :D

Comment: @Izzy Comment CleanUp Completed ! :P

Answer (score 1):

No,they will not remain open because in order to fix your device it needs to be opened up and that means battery of the device will be removed...etc ! So, no worries about it at all if it gets fixed your parents wouldn't be able to see the opened incognito tabs. because after a reboot they are usually not re-opened automatically !